# broadcast / extend boolean array along axis in python

Tags: python, numpy, logical-operators, array-broadcasting

I am trying to broadcast a boolean 1D array along a vector to isolate certain operations.

For example, if my boolean array is:

```
b = array([True False False True])
```

with

```
np.shape(b) = (4,)
```

My matrix I would like to do row wise comparison with is of this form:

```
A = array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]])
```

with

```
np.shape(A) = (4, 3)
```

The end result I would like would be:

```
C = b * A (row-wise comparison) 

C = array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]])
```

I realize that this can be done by slicing, but I need the speed boost from using logical arrays. Is there a way to "extend" the boolean vector so that it works over the rows?

The idea is to be able to calculate a function all in one line so that

```
D = b * A * (some operation done over all vectors) + ~b * A * (some different operation done over all vectors)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `np.where(b, (some operation), (some other operation))`?

Comment: I'm not sure it would work in this case, since the operations I need to do are index based on the vector (i.e, if the vector is at this index, do this). I thought the fastest way to do this as a fully vectorized operation was through the use of logical arrays, rather than slices.

Comment: Looking at the accepted answer, it seems you actually want `np.where(b[:,None], A*..., A*...)`. This ought to be at least as fast as your multiplication above (and if it's not, then you should file a bug against numpy to make it so!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `b`to `2D` keeping the second axis as a singleton dimension (dimension with `length = 1`) and multiply with `A`. Thus, under the hood `b` would be broadcasted to the same shape as of `A` and element-wise multiplications would be performed.

Thus, the vectorized solution would be -

```
A*b[:,None]
```